# Select unique data from one table

Tags: sql, database, select, left-join

I have a diners table:

```
NAME     |   FOOD
-----------------
matthew  |   rice
matthew  |   beans
mark     |   rice
mark     |   beans
Luke     |   rice
john     |   beans
```

I need to extract names that have had only rice, names that have had only beans and both.  A LEFT JOIN would work if they were in separate tables. But I'm having difficulty because they're in one table.

I've tried variants of these 2 statements with no luck:

```
SELECT name 
FROM diners 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT name 
     FROM diners
     WHERE food = 'beans')

SELECT t1.name FROM diners AS t1
LEFT JOIN diners AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t2.food = 'rice'
  AND t2.name IS NULL
```

Comment: When you say no luck, what do you mean?

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: I mean it's returning 0 rows.  For those that only had rice and not beans, I expect: Luke.  Only beans and not rice, I expect john.  For both, I expect matthew and mark

Comment: Recommend using EXISTS and NOT EXISTS with joins. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- names that have had BOTH

```
SELECT NAME FROM diners
WHERE FOOD IN ('RICE','BEANS')
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

-- names that have had only rice

```
SELECT NAME FROM diners
WHERE NAME NOT IN (
SELECT NAME FROM diners
WHERE FOOD NOT IN ('RICE'))
```

--names that have had only beans

```
SELECT NAME FROM diners
WHERE NAME NOT IN (
SELECT NAME FROM diners
WHERE FOOD NOT IN ('BEANS'))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Had Rice only --**

```
    select name from dinner where food='rice' and name in 
    (select name from diners group by name having count(name)=1);
```

**Had Beans only --**

```
   select name from dinner where food='beans' and name in 
   (select name from diners group by name having count(name)=1);
```

**Had Both --**

```
   select name from diners where food in ('rice','beans') group by name 
   having count(name)>1;
```

Comment: "Rice only" and "beans only" didn't work.  They returned everyone that had  rice and everyone that had beans.  However "had both" worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    create table #diners (name nvarchar(20), food nvarchar(20))
    insert into #diners values ('matthew','rice')
    insert into #diners values ('matthew','beans')
    insert into #diners values ('mark','rice')
    insert into #diners values ('mark','beans')
    insert into #diners values ('luke','rice')
    insert into #diners values ('john','beans')


    --  only rice
    select  d1.name
    from        #diners d1 
    where       d1.food = 'rice' and
            d1.name not in (select d2.name from #diners d2 where d2.food != 'rice')

    --  only beans
    select  d1.name
    from        #diners d1 
    where       d1.food = 'beans' and
            d1.name not in (select d2.name from #diners d2 where d2.food != 'beans')

    --  both
    select  d1.name
    from        #diners d1 
    where       d1.food = 'rice' and
            d1.name in (select d2.name from #diners d2 where d2.food = 'beans')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using GROUP_CONCAT?

`SELECT name GROUP_CONCAT(food) AS foodchain FROM diners GROUP BY name`

You can then check if foodchain equals rice or beans or whatever in your application. There's likely an easy solution within SQL but this should work too.

Answer (score 0):

To get the diners that have only had 'beans':

```
SELECT  distinct name 
FROM    DINERS D1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT NULL FROM DINERS D2 WHERE FOOD = 'rice' AND D1.NAME = D2.NAME)
 AND EXISTS 
 (SELECT * FROM DINERS D2 WHERE FOOD = 'beans' AND D1.NAME = D2.NAME);
```

To get the diners that have only had 'rice':

```
SELECT  distinct name 
FROM    DINERS D1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT NULL FROM DINERS D2 WHERE FOOD = 'beans' AND D1.NAME = D2.NAME)
 AND EXISTS 
 (SELECT * FROM DINERS D2 WHERE FOOD = 'rice' AND D1.NAME = D2.NAME);
```

To get only the diners that have had both:

```
SELECT  distinct name 
FROM    DINERS D1
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM DINERS D2 WHERE FOOD = 'rice' AND D1.NAME = D2.NAME)
AND EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM DINERS D2 WHERE FOOD = 'beans' AND D1.NAME = D2.NAME);
```